# Difference between 'come about', 'come around' and 'goes'

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference in meaning between the following three sentences?

1. Let's see how it comes about.
2. Let's see how it goes.
3. Let's see how it comes around.

These words/phrasal verbs are -- by a close approximation -- the synonyms of 'happen'. I'm interested in the specific difference in usage, if any.

Comment: What did you find when you looked them in the dictionary?

Comment: these words/phrasal verbs are-- by a close approximation-- the synonyms of 'happen'. I'm interested in the specific difference in usage, if any.

Comment: I understand now what you're asking. But now that I understand what you're asking, I need to know that in what dictionary did you look up the meaning of **come around **? I know about the other two.

Comment: **Let us see how it goes** is to do with the process as in, how the thing will proceed and not the outcome itself. **Come about** is almost exclusive to navy/nautical terminology when they want to say that they are shifting to a new direction. It also means *happen* but we generally avoid it to stay clear of confusion. In your question, it does mean *happen*. It is a synonym.

Comment: **Come around** means to happen again or go back to a previous position. It shouldn't be used for something happening for the first time.

Comment: You are not using "comes about" and "comes around" correctly.  They are not direct replacements for "goes".

Answer (score 0):

**Come about**, at [thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Come+about)

> 1. **come to pass**. **Happen**, **take place**, as in How did this quarrel come about? or When did this new development come to pass? Shakespeare used the first term, first recorded in 1315, in Hamlet (5:2): "How these things came about." The variant, dating from the late 1400s, appears often in the Bible, as in, "And it came to pass ... that there went out a decree from Caesar Augustus" (Luke 2:1).

**go/goes**
at [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go)

> proceed or move along in a specified way

**Come around**
at [thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+around)

> 1. **Make a circuit**; also, arrive casually or visit. For example, The milkman comes around every day at this time, or You should come round more often. [Early 1800s] Also see come by, def.
> 2. **Change in a favorable way**, as in I was sure you would come around and see it my way. [Early 1800s]
> 3. **Recover consciousness, be restored to a normal condition**, as in The smelling salts quickly made her come round. [Mid-1800s]

While we were waiting to see how the product launch **goes**, server failure **came about** and our bad luck **came around** with it.

Comment: Your answer is good. Make it better by citing the dictionary source.

Comment: last line which comprises all these words has been written by me.Rest of the definition is from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com//

Comment: I mean name the source for the definitions for each of the words you provided.

Comment: The reference has been updated.

Comment: Look at your answer now. Specify definition for every word you suggest as an answer.

Comment: @vickyace-Thanks.Will try to follow this from now onwards.

Comment: Also note that the third definition for *come around* is not needed in this context. So in the future, posit definitions that are relevant to the issue just as you did with the word *go*.